# IF statement not functioning - R

Tags: r

I have a variable `sleptim` that contains a number of hours slept which ranges from 2 hrs to 19 hrs.
If number of hours slept <6, I want sleptim1 var. take the new value "Below Normal"
If number of hours slept >9, I want sleptim1 var. take the new value "Above Normal"
Else "Normal"
but The result of the new categorical variable is not functioning well.

Help please

```
for (i in 500: 1500)
{
    if(question4$sleptim1[i]<6) 
    {question4$sleptim1[i] <- "Below Normal"}


    else if(question4$sleptim1[i]>9)
    {question4$sleptim1[i] <- "Above Normal"}


    else
    {question4$sleptim1[i] <- "Normal"}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "The result of the new categorical variable is not functioning well"?

Comment: look at `?cut` - it will be much easier and faster to use that your loop.

Comment: In a data frame the class of the column is only one type.  In your example you are attempting to convert an column of integers to a column of characters strings.  I suggest creating a new column to store the desired results.

Comment: You're converting numeric column to character column after first integer.

Comment: If number of hours slept <6, I want sleptim1 var. take the new value "Below Normal"
If number of hours slept >9, I want sleptim1 var. take the new value "Above Normal"
Else "Normal"

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this kind of looping, but this results seems to be what you want. Instead of overwriting `question4$sleptim1` you have to create new column `question4$sleptim1_Wanted` and store you results there.

```
question4$sleptim1_Wanted <- NA

for (i in 500: 1500)

{
    if(question4$sleptim1[i]<6) 
    {question4$sleptim1_Wanted[i] <- "Below Normal"}


    else if(question4$sleptim1[i]>9)
    {question4$sleptim1_Wanted[i] <- "Above Normal"}


    else
    {question4$sleptim1_Wanted[i] <- "Normal"}
}
```

Comment: @RofaidaGoda did this solution work for you? If so, can you please accept the answer